# React Native, component is not closing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I created a shopping app with react native and redux, I'm facing a problem that when a user click buy it should view a component in bottom that will show total amount and view cart button and when user remove item from cart and cart is empty, it should close/state set to false, but it's not going away. Can anyone tell me what's wrong, below is my code
reducer.js

```
 if (action.type === SHOW_CART) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
    if (addedItem == 0) {
      return {
        ...state,
        show: console.log(state.showCart),
      };
    } else {
      return {
        ...state,
        show: console.log(action.showCart),
      };
    }
  }
const initialstate = {
  showChart: false,
}
```

that's my reducer where I'm handling that function

action.js

```
export const showCart = (id) => {
  return {
    type: SHOW_CART,
    showCart: true,
    id,
  };
};
```

that's my action where I describe it's action

ViewCart.js

```
 <View>
        {this.props.show ? (
          <View style={styles.total}>
            <Text style={styles.totaltext}>Total:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.priceTotal}>{this.props.total}</Text>
            <View style={styles.onPress}>
              <Text
                style={styles.pressText}
                onPress={() => RootNavigation.navigate("Cart")}
              >
                View Cart
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        ) : null}
      </View>
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    total: state.clothes.total,
    show: state.clothes.show,
  };
};
```

that's the function where I'm using that reducer

Answer (score 0):

By my opinion, the problem is located in your reducer.js file

```
if (action.type === SHOW_CART) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
    if (addedItem.quantity > 0) {
      return {
        ...state,
        showCart: action.showCart, // here was the problem
      };
    }
 }
 const initialstate = {
     showChart: false,
 }
```

Please try it and tell me what goes on.
And let me suggest to add another test to your `if` statement :
if (addedItem && addedItem.quantity > 0)
To avoid probable trouble by an unexpected manipulation

Comment: nop, i did console.log and update my code, i also updated it here , it's making my condition true when i add an item in cart but when i remove it, it's not making it false again